# Rxjs: takeUntil() wrong behavior after observable was completed and started again?

Tags: rxjs, observable, subject

I have the follow code:

```
 const reconnectorAfterPingPongFailed$ = Observable.of('timeout').delay(5000).takeUntil(this.serviceAlive$);

        reconnectorAfterPingPongFailed$
          .race(this.pingPong$)
          .take(1)
          .repeat()
          .takeUntil(this.serviceAlive$)
          .do(() => console.log("[ping-pong]:","repeated"))
          .subscribe((data: any) => {
// some code
});
```

what do I expect from this code ?

1. Every N seconds we get from server some "pong"-message, which used to make this.pingPong$.next("pong")
2. It goes to race(), where if pong is there we get "pong"-command in subscribe or "timeout" if "pong" is not there for delay more than 5000 sec (event comes from `reconnectorAfterPingPongFailed$`)
3. I would like to process subscription only if my service is alive, let's say while I'm log in.
4. So when I'm logging out I make `.next()` and `.complete()`:
5. When I logged out first time I don't see console.log message from `.do()`
6. When I log again this subject is recreated again private `serviceAlive$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();`
7. And when I logged out again it seems to be that this code `.do(() => console.log("[ping-pong]:","repeated"))` still working

Comment: This needs a [mcve].

Comment: I'm confused: In _"5"_ you say it's not working and in _"7"_ you say it's still working.